# Base type for entity framework core entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am working on a ASP.Net MVC Core 2 application.

I have some tables/entities.

I want to write a `TagHelper` which takes an attribute. This attribute is the model and can be any of my Entities class.

Here is some code:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("mytag", Attributes = "model")]
public class MyTagHelper : TagHelper
{

    [HtmlAttributeName("model")]
    public GenericTypeINeedCommonToAllMyEntities model { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
       ....
    }
```

and there what I want to do in my cshtml views:

View1.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Entitie1>
...
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    ...
    <mytag model="@item" />
}
```

View2.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Entitie2>
...
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    ...
    <mytag model="@item" />
}
```

As you can see i want to use this tag helper with any kind of Entity.

My question is what should i put instead of `GenericTypeINeedCommonToAllMyEntities` type ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the model once you have it? This is the most important question. Without knowing this, your `model` property should probably be of type [`ModelExpression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.modelexpression?view=aspnetcore-2.0) or [`ModelExplorer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.modelexplorer?view=aspnetcore-2.0). You could then use a for loop and access each item in your model by index.

Comment: In fact a want to do a pagination system. This is not really the model but a collection of model's item